# Aurelia custom element with a table with a slot in it

Tags: aurelia

I have an Aurelia custom element that I want to render a table. It needs to control paging and such against an OData source. I would like the consumer of the custom element to provide the row template. The template for my element looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="odata-table">
    <div class="row">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th repeat.for="column of columns">
              ${column.title}
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <slot></slot>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then when I consume it:

```
<odata-table view-model.ref="resultsTable" url="http://localhost:5000/odata/v1/FooBar">
    <tr repeat.for="record of resultsTable.records" slot="rows">
      <td>${record.Foo}</td>
      <td>${record.Bar}</td>
    </tr>
</odata-table>
```

The rows never show up inside my tbody. If I move the slot outside the table and replace tr & td with a ul & li, it renders the data just fine.

Is there something I need to do to allow a slot inside a table element?

Comment: what do you intend with `view-model.ref="resultsTable"`? It seems that you are trying to "set" the view-model.

Comment: view-model.ref gets a reference to the custom element's view model. That allows me to call methods and access properties on the element. In this case, I am iterating the records it retrieved from my odata source. It also allows me to change pages and configuration after the fact based on user input. This code completely works if I move the <slot></slot> outside the table and change the <tr>... to a <ul>...

Comment: I haven't tested it, but if you haven't tried already, I recommend trying <slot containerless>. I've written a little bit about other table templating patterns in my blog here: http://davismj.me/blog/advanced-tables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the browser itself, not Aurelia. The browser comes along and it sees the `<slot>` element and knows that it is not a valid child element of `<tbody>` so it strips it out. This is where the `as-element` attribute comes into the fray.

However, in your particular scenario, the `as-element` which allows you to decorate a HTML element and have Aurelia parse it as something else, might not work here as you are trying to use the `<slot>` element which is essentially content projection.

This will most likely require a redesign of your application. Consider dynamically composing your markup using bindable values passed in through the custom element instead.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Aurelia to render the element in a shadow DOM that doesn't strip things out? I tries the @shadowDom decorator, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this really sucks donkeys! Avoiding duplication by creating template tables is a great use of this feature - perhaps there should be a way to get `slot` working as an `as-element` or some other custom attribute on the tbody?

Comment: btw, at the moment - this works in Firefox but breaks in Chrome